# Use sed to strip out multiple cases with varying names

Tags: sed

I have an ansible inventory that I need to remove all cases that start with `site2-`.

For example I have a list that includes groups named:

```
[site2-static-web]
site2-ansible
site2-accounts
site2-admin
site2-analytics
site2-audit
site2-botruntime
site2-campaigns
site2-config
site2-coupons
site2-edge
site2-minio
site2-permissions
site2-registry
site2-surveys
site2-websockets
site2-amc-server
site2-static-web
site2-elasticsearch
site2-logstash
site2-kibana
site2-keycloak
site2-pgsql
site2-mysql
site2-rabbitmq
site2-redis
site2-zipkin
```

I tried `sed -i.bak 's/site2-*///g' mmp_default` but all that got me was the `site2` removed with the ends left in.

```
site2-ansible
site2-accounts
```

Became:

```
ansible
accounts
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed '/ansible\|accounts/ !d ; s/site2-//' toto
ansible
accounts
$
```

so I first choose matching lines on words I need separated by \|  then only I cut the useless word "site2-".
You can still add -i.bak if needed